# UIImage array does not appear in ios Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

I'm building a simple tic tac toe game and I would like to same each "X" or "O" in an array so that when the user leaves the screen and comes back the game reloads.

I can get it to print to the output screen but it doesn't show up in the IOS simulator. I've only have the first two squares coded because I was hoping to get the array to work before I moved on to the rest.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

var gamePieces3 = NSMutableArray()

class GameViewController3 : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button0 : UIButton !
    @IBOutlet var button1 : UIButton !

    @IBOutlet var spot0 : UIImageView !
    @IBOutlet var spot1 : UIImageView !

    @IBAction func addGamePiece0(button0 : AnyObject) {
        if (goNumber % 2 == 0) {
            let image2 = UIImage(named : "cross.png")
            spot0.image = image2

        }
        else {
            let image1 = UIImage(named : "circle.png")
            spot0.image = image1
        }
        gamePieces3.addObject(spot0)
        goNumber++
    }

    @IBAction func addGamePiece1(button1 : AnyObject) {
        if (goNumber % 2 == 0) {
            let image2 = UIImage(named : "cross.png")
            spot1.image = image2

        }
        else {
            let image1 = UIImage(named : "circle.png")
            spot1.image = image1
        }
        gamePieces3.addObject(spot1)
        goNumber++
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated : Bool) {
        print(gamePieces3)

    }        
}
```

Comment: I mean, you have to draw it in a view if you want to see it on the screen...

Comment: What exactly is not showing.. the println() statement or the images?

Comment: It's the images that aren't showing up when you go back into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more things you need to implement in your code if you want your app to "remember" where it left off from last app close or exit. Since you only want to store which button location stores "cross" or "circle", I think most suitable and easy way to do is using `NSUserDefaults`. It works very similar to a Dictionary. You can put something like "Button0" all the way to "Button8" as keys, and "cross.png" or "circle.png" as value. Every time your `gamePieces3` is changed, you need to change that `NSUserDefaults` accordingly. Then in you `videDidLoad`, you want to read from your `NSUserDefaults`. Scan through `NSUserDefaults`, and apply "cross.png" or "circle.png" accordingly to controller's view.

Comment: Thanks toadead, you've sent me in the right direction. I'm wondering if you can help me out a bit more. I'm starting to code in circles. I've added the NSUserDefaults but it's still not appearing in the simulator. I know i'm missing a step or two but I can't figure it out.
For the button i've added:
defaults.setObject(gamePieces3, forKey: "button0") 
defaults.synchronize()
For viewDidLoad:
if defaults.objectForKey("button0") != nil {
defaults.objectForKey("button0") as NSMutableArray}
        gamePieces3 = defaults.objectForKey("button0") as NSMutableArray

Comment: The first thing you should focus on is creating a working app without that "remember" functionality and go from there. Also you shouldn't use `button` and `spot` to represent one thing. All UIButton has image property, so you can set that property directly. I've done this Tic Tac Toe practice, so I know. Here is the link to [my github's tic-tac-toe](https://github.com/toadead/Tic-Tac-Toe) you can refer to if you get stuck. My app doesn't remember where's left off when re-enter though.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.addSubview(<ImageView with your image>);
```